# PayPal Express Checkout Error 10413, but everything adds up

Tags: paypal

Customer receives a 10413 error, but everything adds.
I suspect it is the Discount Code, but I am not sure.
Here is the relevant part of what is being submitted (expanded for clarity).
Can anyone spot the problem?

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=54.79

PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=76.40
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
ALLOWNOTE=1
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=-30.56
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT=0
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=8.95
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0.00

INVNO=093543
ADDROVERRIDE=1

L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Round 2mm Silver HotFix RhineStuds
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=49267
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=0.72
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=10
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=Round 2mm Gold HotFix RhineStuds
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1=49231
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=0.8
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=10
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME2=Round 3mm Silver HotFix RhineStuds
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER2=49367
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT2=0.72
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY2=10
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME3=Round 4mm Silver HotFix RhineStuds
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER3=49467
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT3=0.78
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY3=10
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME4=Round 5mm Silver HotFix RhineStuds
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER4=49567
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT4=0.84
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY4=10
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME5=Round 6mm Silver HotFix RhineStuds
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER5=49567x
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT5=1.44
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY5=10
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME6=Round 3mm Gold HotFix RhineStuds
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER6=49331
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT6=0.72
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY6=10
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME7=Round 4mm Gold HotFix RhineStuds
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER7=49431
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT7=0.78
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY7=10
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME8=Round 5mm Gold HotFix RhineStuds
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER8=49531
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT8=0.84
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY8=10

PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD=InstantPaymentOnly
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?

Comment: No, still waiting on someone to spot the problem.  Everything looks good, but it does not work.  What am I missing?

Comment: VERSION=78.0
 METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=19.50
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=15.00
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
 ALLOWNOTE=1
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=-0
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT=0
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=4.5
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0.00
 INVNO=123
 ADDROVERRIDE=1
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=4mm Clear
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=25401
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=1.5
 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=10
 LOGOIMG=https://xx.jpg
 PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
 ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD=InstantPaymentOnly
 RETURNURL=http://xx
 CANCELURL=http://xxxx

Comment: just had a really simple request - 1 item + shipping.  It bombed too.  Just posted the code above.  Same routine, some requests work, some requests bomb, and I can't see a pattern.  Any and all assistance would be most appreciated